# C# - Создание динамически подгружаемой библиотеки

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь написать небольшой чит на C#, и хочу, что бы он был в DLL файле. То есть, что бы запустить чит, нужно инжектировать эту самую DLL в процесс игры. Искал сейчас что то в гугле, но ничего понятного и рабочего не нашел.

Я знаю, что в C/C++ для таких DLL существует функция DllMain, это точка входа в DLL. Она вызывается когда пользователь подгружает библиотеку. А есть ли подобная функция на C#, или какие нибудь другие варианты исполнить то, что я хочу?

Comment: [1](https://www.unknowncheats.me/wiki/C_Sharp), [2](https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-/).

Comment: А игра на чём написана?